# Why doesn't the test result view on MTM show the error message field?

Tags: coded-ui-tests, microsoft-test-manager, mtm

I've created a coded UI test to test a basic successful login scenario for a WPF application. I chose the coding approach over the recording approach and I've adopted the page object model. I've integrated this test with TFS and I'm able to execute the test via MTM without any problem. However in the scenario of the test failing I've noticed that the Error Message field in the summary section of the test result view (the one below the Resolution field) does not appear. The error message is available in the TRX file attached in the test run view.

Is there a way for me to get the error message to be displayed in the error message field in the test result view as well?

This is a screenshot of my test result view
[image: test result view screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Usually Assert fail messages show up in the "Error Message" field in MTM. If you dont have one, add it to your testcase and run it again.

Comment: In my case the asser fail message is showing in the TRX of the test run (and so I'm unable to check the messsage if i go to the test case). As you mentioned, I too was under the impression that it should show in the error message field. Any idea as to why it isn't?

Answer (score 0):

Rusty,

I wanted to double check with you. I'm currently unable to see errors in the results view either, however I am able to see the error clearly and cleanly once I look at the test run itself (without opening the .trx).

For what it's worth, I have assertions throughout my tests. In addition, I have an "Assert.Fail" within a catch block that covers all my tests which I have designed in such a way that it does not nest the assertion failures as they bubble up.

It seems this problem is [common among users of MTM](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/02ad91a0-ebb8-4660-ae2c-9fab81e8239b/error-message-not-showing-for-all-automated-tests-in-the-test-run-mtm-codedui-visual-studio-2012?forum=vsmantest), and Microsoft refuses to acknowledge it. If you'll forgive some opinion, I believe that the MTM product is dead in the water as Microsoft continues to add functionality to TFS web access, with this feature still being unavailable through that.